# Octobercms : Undefined Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I know there is a lot similar questions of this one. But non of them fixed my issue.

I run php artisan serve without any issue but when i try to load the page I get this error with no explicit message:

Undefined
Exception

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

[image]

I've got the same project file + php version + laravel version that my teamate but he does not get the error.

Do you have any more ideas please ?

Comment: Yes I already did and it does not change anything :/

Comment: sounds like it couldn't find the route for the URI you are trying to access  `RouteCollection@match` ... trying to match the request to a route

Comment: Yeah i feel it's a route issue cause i can't access any of the routes but I tried to clear the cache route etc. The only clue I've got is when I run php artisan route:list I get this error message: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Comment: well find out the line of that error and figure out why you are getting this new error, use the stacktrace to walk back to your code if you have to ... this is debugging

Comment: what URL you are trying to access ?

Comment: the main / but non of the url works anyway